# PHP page not returning value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a value from a database through ajax and php.
The ajax code is as follows:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#buyprice").change(function() {

                    if ($("#sname").val() == "") {
                        alert("Enter Stock name.");
                    } else {

                        var sn = $("#sname").val();
                        alert(sn);
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                var x = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            };
                        };
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstockprice.php?q="+sn, true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        alert("here");
                    };
                    alert("here");
                    var bp = $("#buyprice").val();
                    alert(bp);
                    alert(x.val());
                    if(bp>(1.1*x)||bp<(1.1*x)){
                        alert("Price violating 10% constraint.");


                    }
                    alert("here");
                });

            });
        </script>
```

The php page is as follows:

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['q'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stock_market');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT stock_price FROM live_prices WHERE stock_name = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: No output being output via `echo`, `print` or anything from your PHP

Comment: What output are you *expecting* from this PHP code, and why?  I see no indication of actually outputting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use echo or return to return something from php.

```
   <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#buyprice").change(function() {

                    if ($("#sname").val() == "") {
                        alert("Enter Stock name.");
                    } else {

                        var sn = $("#sname").val();
                        alert(sn);
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                var x = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            };
                        };
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstockprice.php?q="+sn, true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        alert("here");
                    };
                    alert("here");
                    var bp = $("#buyprice").val();
                    alert(bp);
                    alert(x);
                    if(bp>(1.1*x)||bp<(1.1*x)){
                        alert("Price violating 10% constraint.");


                    }
                    alert("here");
                });

            });
        </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stock_market');
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
          }

        mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
        $sql="SELECT stock_price FROM live_prices WHERE stock_name = '".$q."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        mysqli_close($con);

        echo $row['stock_price'];


    ?>
```

Comment: I don't want to display the result I just want the value to do some processing.

Comment: here echo wont display anything in browser since you are calling the php file using ajax. Instead echo acts as a return statement here.

Comment: @Jonah: Where are you doing this "processing"?  I don't see you using the value for anything in PHP or in JavaScript...

Comment: its the x value in the ajax part. So basically the input value should not be less or greater than the value from the database by 10% that is what I want to achieve. And the values in the database keep changing.

Comment: Yes I did. I still cant retrieve the value.

Comment: @Jonah: What debugging did you do for that?  Use something like FireBug or Chrome tools.  When you actually echo the value from PHP, what is the actual response from the server?  What does `.responseText` contain?

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. But i went with the solution given in the next post.

Answer (score 0):

The php script needs to echo the value. This does not display the value on your page, it merely makes the value avalailble to the javascript.

I would suggest using jquery and use the built in ajax functionality. This works much easier.

See the [jquery ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and an example straight from there:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: That is great. Good luck with the rest.